# JS assignment operator: Assigning to a variable determined by conditional operator expression

Tags: javascript

I tried to do this today. JavaScript doesn't let me do it.

Is there no workaround?

```
$ node
> var x = []
undefined
> var y = [2]
undefined
> var f = false
undefined
> (f ? x : y).push(3)
2
> x
[]
> y
[ 2, 3 ]
> (f ? x : y) = [] // clear y
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at yada yada...
```

Here's the conundrum. I could write this:

```
var z = (f ? x : y);
z = [];
```

This actually doesn't work to clear `y` because `x`, `y`, and `z` are references (they are not primitive types)

Obviously `f` as presented here is a simple triviality, the idea is I want to use the assignment operator on an expression and it appears not to be powerful enough to work that way.

Comment: It should be: `f ? x = [] : y = [];`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I've never attempted to use anything other than the name of a variable on the left side of equal to. The error indeed appears to indicate that the use of an expression here is illegal but I havent been taught this.

Comment: @user6188402 That's... amazing

Comment: If `x` and `y` are global variables, then you can do `window[f?"x":"y"]=[];`

Comment: @RaymondChen. In this case, a clever way is: `window['yx'[+f]] = [];`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What you've written there is essentially like saying, `1 = 2` which doesn't make sense at all. i.e. it evaluates to `[2] = []`. Your `z` case works, because now you are assigning a new value to a variable, and not assigning a value to a value. Edit: I think I see it now, you want to make `y = []`, if `f` is false?

Comment: @user6188402 That is not clever, it is a horrible anti-pattern.

Comment: I want to clear `y`. Yeah you do make a good point that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. There's not really a way I can justify having the `?:` operator function on "lvalues", as it were.

Comment: @torazaburo. My bad, old habit of code-golfing... ;)

Comment: @user6188402 holy crap I just understood what that does. For shame! Shame on you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that the assignment operator is or is not "powerful". It's a basic feature of JS that variables do not hold references to other variables, or in other words, you cannot "alias" variables. To put it a different way, you cannot compute or otherwise hold a "pointer" to a variable.

The obvious workaround is to use an object property instead, in which case you can use the property name as a kind of "pointer":

```
var o = {x: [], y: [2]};
var z = f ? 'x' : 'y';
o[z] = [];
```